# incremental and decremental for loop optimization

Tags: performance, for-loop

I was recently told to improve a for loop is convenient to use decremental for loop instead of incremental loop, like

```
For(int i=0; i<Limit;i++) 
{ 
 //code
} 

For(int i=Limit-1; i >=0; i--) 
{ 
 //code
}
```

I am not seeing why some people would recommend using this, their argument was

"using incremental for loops increases the number of validations inside the loop. when using decremental loops validations and processing time are reduced"

Comment: Well there is an instruction "branch if equal 0" but honestly this is terrible advice, I would be stunned if you got a noticeable performance difference from this switch.

Comment: +1 to @jozefg, especially keeping in mind that you really should use iterators instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times, you will see something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
}
```

But often you could do instead

```
for(int i = list.length(); i >= 0; i--) {
}
```

That way, `list.length()` is called once.

Of course, this is also a possiblity:

```
int length = list.length();
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
}
```

But the first way was shorter.

Rarely do I ever think of fixing a real performance problem with such a trivial and (usually) inconsequential fix. And if for some reason `.length()` is really eating CPU time, I prefer the last way.

Comment: I think that `length()` in a loop should be sorted out by a compiler and evaluated only once. Otherwise, there is also `--i` instead of `i--` if you want to go there... As Paul duly mentioned, any of these are not the issues to consider when you want to speed up your code.